# Reliable column count in a table with multiple <tr>'s

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, multiple-columns

I have a table that is approximately like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Mars</th>
    <th>Venus</th>
    <th>Jupiter</th>
    <th>Pluto</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Ignore the data -- it's really bad.

I am trying to count the number of `th` under the last `tr` within `thead`.

With jQuery, I did the following `$($0).find('thead th').length` to get the number of columns, but in my application, I would get 8, since technically there is 8 `th` under `thead`. I would like to have a solution where I only count all the `th` in the LAST `tr` (assume my table has multiple `tr` within `thead`).

I am basically trying to have a reliable way to count the number of columns in my table.

EDIT:

Here is a CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWByqW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's pretty easy .

```
var ths = document.querySelector('thead tr:last-child');

console.log(ths.childElementCount);
```

Comment: This worked - and is the simplest most readable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use direct children selectors: https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/
and last selector: https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

```
$($0).find('thead > tr :last > th').length
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/DrevanTonder/pen/QdZjPa